# Invoke Apex Class with Process Builder

Tags: apex, process-builder, invocable-method

I am attempting to start this Apex class with Process Builder, triggered by a field change. I've never done this before and I'm unsure what invoke code needs to be added in order to accomplish this. I tried adding @InvocableMethod but I'm getting an error telling me this :

```
Compile Error: Unsupported parameter type String. 
Valid invocable parameters must be List types like List<T> 
where T is a supported type at line 26 column 27
```

It is a class which is currently being invoked with a Lightning Component button in a record.

```
public class UpdateContactPCRController {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static String  updateContact(String recordId){        
       
        String contactId = '';       
        
        List<Contact> contactToBeupdate = new List<Contact>();        
        
        if(String.isNotBlank(recordId)){            
            
            List<Program_Contact_Role__c> programContacList = [SELECT Id,Contact__c,Program_Name__c FROM Program_Contact_Role__c WHERE Id =:recordId AND Contact__c != null];
            contactId = programContacList[0].Contact__c;
            
            if(String.isNotBlank(contactId)){
                
                contactToBeupdate = [Select Id,Pardot_Action_Trigger__c,PCR_Register_Button_Link__c,PCR_URL_for_UI__c FROM Contact Where Id =: contactId Limit 1];                
                
                contactToBeupdate[0].Program_Contact_Role_Id__c = recordId;
            }
                        List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> programCommunicationRecs = [Select Id,Name,
                                  Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name,Receipient__c,                
                                              From Program_Communication_Recipients__c Where 
                                                           Program_Communication__r.Program__c =: programContacList[0].Program_Name__c AND 
                                                           Receipient__c =: programContacList[0].Id];                                           
                                
                
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c = String.valueOf(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c);                                                    

        if(contactToBeupdate.size() > 0){
            update contactToBeupdate;  
        }
        
        return 'Updated Successfully';
    }
}
    //Calling  Http_Utility_Pardot class pardotCreateProspect method for the creation of Prospect record.
    String returnedResponseFromPardot = Http_Utility_Pardot.pardotCreateProspect(new Set<Id> {contactToBeupdate[0].Id});
```

Thank you very much for any help you can give with this. It is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is not an allowed argument because Invocable Methods must be passed Lists. Below is taken from the [Salesforce developer documentation on Invocable Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm). You will need to make your method accept a `List<String>` and return a `List<String>` or a another List type.

## InvocableMethod Considerations

### Implementation Notes

- The invocable method must be static and public or global, and its class must be an outer class.
- Only one method in a class can have the InvocableMethod annotation.
- Other annotations can’t be used with the InvocableMethod annotation.

### Inputs and Outputs

- There can be at most one input parameter and its data type must be one of the following:
- A list of a primitive data type or a list of lists of a primitive data type – the generic Object type is not supported.
- A list of an sObject type or a list of lists of an sObject type.
- A list of the generic sObject type (List) or a list of lists of the generic sObject type (List<List>).
- A list of a user-defined type, containing variables of the supported types above or user-defined Apex types, with the InvocableVariable annotation. Create a custom global or public Apex class to implement your data type, and make sure that your class contains at least one member variable with the invocable variable annotation.

### If the return type is not Null, the data type returned by the method must be one of the following:

- A list of a primitive data type or a list of lists of a primitive data type – the generic Object type is not supported.
- A list of an sObject type or a list of lists of an sObject type.
- A list of the generic sObject type (List) or a list of lists of the generic sObject type (List<List>).
- A list of a user-defined type, containing variables of the supported types above or user-defined Apex types, with the InvocableVariable annotation. Create a custom global or public Apex class to implement your data type, and make sure that your class contains at least one member variable with the invocable variable annotation.

Comment: thank you so much for this input. I'm going over it and I don't know how to convert these lists to the acceptable data types. Is that even possible ? Will all three of the lists need to be changed ? Thanks again.

Comment: It sounds like I might just be better off creating a trigger which will call the class...? Would that involve too much ? Is the only thing I would need to set the recordid ?

Comment: This is my opinion, but if you're already writing Apex for an invocable, you're probably best writing a trigger. You can make them very efficient compared to process builders. The _reason_ why invocable methods need to be bulkified is that process builders are also bulkified. So I think, in your case, if you keep the Invocable Method you want the method signature to look like: `public static void updateContact(List<Id> recordIds)`. How you handle the DML is dependent upon the process builder, because you could return `List<Database.SaveResult>`, the records you updated, or something else.

Comment: Thank you @nbrown. I think I am going to just attempt to write a trigger which will accomplish it all. I included this in a comment I left for another response to me. I would have included you in that but I was unable to include two references in one comment. Any input you can give to that one would also be appreciated. Thank you very much in this.

Comment: Thanks @Zoom_v, if my answer helped please remember to accept it as the answer.

Comment: No problem - done. Is there an easy trigger which could be used to simply start the class, using an IF to only start it with a specific field change ? And to set recordid ?

Comment: I don't think there's one particular trigger to start you off with. What I would search for is "Apex Trigger framework". You'll find a number of blogs about how to best build your triggers to conform to best practices, make them traceable, and easy to test. Here is a good example: http://www.salesforcenextgen.com/apex-trigger-framework/

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the invocable method as if it were called in bulk; hence the requirement that the input argument must be a collection.

That is, if Process Builder runs on batch of n records, and each executes an Action block that does an invocable call, SFDC batches these up into *one* actual invocable execution (per action block)

So, you basically have to bulkify this invocable method like you would a trigger, except instead of a `Trigger.new` collection to iterate over, you would have

```
@InvocableMethod
public static String[]  updateContact(Id[] pcrIds){

     List<Program_Contact_Role__c> programContacList = [SELECT Id,Contact__c,Program_Name__c 
       FROM Program_Contact_Role__c 
       WHERE Id =:pcrIds AND Contact__c != null];
     ...
     //  collect all the Contact__c in programContacList
     //  query or construct Contact objects
     //  update logic (bulkified)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @cropredy. - After reading the responses I've gotten I think I am just going to attempt to get the method going w/ a trigger rather than make all of these changes. Is there an easy trigger which could be used to simply start the class, using an IF to only start it with a specific field change ? And to set recordid ?

Comment: I tried implementing this and apparently the callout which executed at this line : contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c = String... but I need the class to be invoked by a field change. Would I be able to accomplish this instead with a trigger which would execute BeforeUpdate ? If so, what would a trigger which would invoke upon a field change look like in this case ?

Comment: Process Builder can detect field changes - use `PRIORVALUE` and `ISCHANGED` functions

Comment: The problem isn't recognizing the changes. I believe the problem is happening because the updates are happening before the callout. This explains it : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328873&type=1&mode=1  ; So somehow I think I need to use a BeforeUpdate trigger in order to invoke the class...?

Comment: you didn't say in OP that you are doing a callout from the invocable. Please use [edit] to elaborate

Comment: I'm sorry for not including the callout in the OP. I'm sorry, I didn't realize it would be an issue until I started testing with Process Builder. I've added it right at the end. It is the last two lines. Any help you can give would be very appreciate. Again, I apologize for this.

Comment: Do the callout in a future or queueable class. You won't be able to return the result of the callout back to the PB.  This would be true for triggers as well.